# How to select the nth row in a SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.;Database=Soft;Integrated Security=true");
connString.Open();

using (connString)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees", connString);
}
```

I get here........................................

Comment: So you want for example the data at row 9? Can you provide some sample data and expected results? Please.

Comment: SQL doesn't have a concept of "rows" being in any specific order unless you specify the order based on an `ORDER BY` clause. So your `SELECT * FROM Employees` will result in an arbitrary order.

Comment: example line 9 and I'll get the name from line nine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `OFFSET`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Employees
ORDER BY {Your Column} --Replace with correct column
OFFSET @N-1 Rows FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

An alternative method is to use a CTE and number every row (personally I prefer the above though):

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {Your Column}) AS RN --Replace with correct column
    FROM dbo.Employees)
SELECT {Columns, apart from RN} --Replace with correct columns
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = @N;
```

To add the parameter `@N` to you command you would use the following:

```cs
command.Parameters.Add("@N", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@N"].Value = RowNumber; //Or whatever the object/variable that has the value of @N
```

*Both these solution assume that the first row is row 1, not 0. Also (obviously) you need to replace the parts in the braces (`{}`).*